# Node.js / Why async.eachSeries doesn't call the callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code using [eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
 var allLetters = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
 async.eachSeries(allLetters, function(arrObj, callback){
                saveAllToS3(arrMain, arrObj);
                console.log("Reach here");
        }, function (err){
        console.log("callback is called");
           if (err){
        console.log(err);
        } else {
        console.log("Completed");
        }
        });
```

I see that `saveAllToS3` is execute only one time, and the callback is not called ("callback is called" is not printed, and also no error or "Completed" is printed).

Only "Reach here" is printed.

I want that saveAllToS3 will call 4 times. First, the function will be called with "0", after it finished, the function will be called with "1" and so on..

Comment: Why don't you run those in parallel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Async can only proceed to the next input item when you tell it that the current iteration is finished. You do this by invoking the callback that it provides to your function:

```
 var allLetters = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
 async.eachSeries(allLetters, 
    function(arrObj, done){
            saveAllToS3(arrMain, arrObj);
            console.log("Reach here");
            done();
    }, 
    function (err){
       console.log("callback is called");
       if (err) {
           console.log(err);
       } else {
           console.log("Completed");
       }
    });
```

I find it useful to call the callback argument something like `done` to make the code more explicit.

Comment: when `done()` is called, what happens? It go to the next iteration, or it go to `function(err){console.log("callback is called");...}`?

Comment: It should go to the next iteration. the function(err) should be called after you finish going through the list or if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 3):

The point of `async.*()` is that the intermediate callbacks you pass are *asynchronous* – they aren't considered to be finished until they call their `callback` parameter.

Since you never call the callback, your first callback never finishes.

Comment: I don't understand how async will know to continue to the next letter? In my code, it execute saveAllToS3 only on "1"

Comment: @OrSmith: It will proceed when you call the callback to tell it that the previous one is finished.